# why isn't my font face loading?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I just scored a sweet font called Cubano Regular and it's my first time using @font-face. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right but my code is :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CubanoRegular';
  src: url('...fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('...fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.eot')format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('...fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('...fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('...fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.svg#')format('svg');
```

I'm a rookie and it would be awesome if someone could help out!

Comment: check the path of the file `../fonts` or `/fonts`

Comment: can you post your directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

You path isn't correct.

```
src: url('.../fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.eot');
```

Answer (score 1):

Then problem is that you are not specifing the relative path correctly,

try

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CubanoRegular';
  src: url('../fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.eot')format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/cubano-regular-webfont.svg#')format('svg');
```

hopefully that solves your problem.

Keep in mind:

. = current directory
../ = one directory above

so in the following tree structure

```
index.html
  -some-folder
    -other.html
```

the relative path to index.html from other.html is "../index.html"

hope that makes any sense,

good luck

Answer (score -2):

Check the path of the file and specify file permission, who and what can read, write, modify and access them, change for 777.